# Loading router's paths from external files

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I' trying to build an app that can be used from different country in different language.
The idea is to have paths that uses good keywords for SEO in each country.

The json file loaded depends on the path url: 
`/uk, /fr, /es loads uk.js, fr.js or es.js`

So I'm trying to do something like this :

**root.rooting.ts**

```
import {Routes, RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
const base = document.location.pathname.split('/')[1];
const paths = require('./' + base + '.js');

const appRoutes: Routes = paths;

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

**uk.js**

```
export var paths = [
  { path: 'house',   loadChildren: 'app/+house/+house.module'},
  { path: '**', loadChildren: 'app/+404/+404.module'}
];
```

**fr.js**

```
export var paths = [
  { path: 'maison',   loadChildren: 'app/+house/+house.module'},
  { path: '**', loadChildren: 'app/+404/+404.module'}
];
```

**es.js**

```
export var paths = [
  { path: 'casa',   loadChildren: 'app/+house/+house.module'},
  { path: '**', loadChildren: 'app/+404/+404.module'}
];
```

How Can I implement this? Is it crazy to do that?

Answer (score 1):

NgModule will be called before constructor of your any component cause it is
decorator but there is work around for it that is you can extend decorator for more read following article

http://myrighttocode.org/blog/typescript/angular2/decorators/angular2-custom-decorators

Comment: Ok so if I understand correctly I should include a js file in order to extend make my own decorator and load router path from there. But how would I use it in `root.rooting.ts`? Great answer. I did not know that!

Comment: you can look at https://scotch.io/tutorials/simple-language-translation-in-angular-2-part-1 for more info which can help you