# Angular 2 dynamic routing doesn't work when try to access by URL

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing, angular-routing, angular-router

I am trying to archive dynamic routing in my Angular application. I have completed following functionalities so far.

- Add routing to an existing angular component by user input.
- Remove routing from an existing angular application.

I have used `router.resetConfig` to do this.

My problem is that whatever the new dynamic route I have added cannot be accessed by typing in the URL. it gives me following error.

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'module3'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'module3'
```

Here is my code

**app.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: Module1Component
  },
  {
    path: 'module2',
    component: Module2Component
  }
];
```

**app.component.html**

```
<div>
  <h2><a routerLink="">Module1</a></h2>
  <h2><a routerLink="module2">Module2</a></h2>
  <h2><a routerLink="module3">Module3</a></h2>
  <input type="button" value="add module 3 to route" (click)="addRoute()"/>
  <input type="button" value="remove module 3 from route" (click)="removeRoute()"/>
</div>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
addRoute(){
    let r: Route = {
      path: 'module3',
      component: Module3Component
    };
    this.router.resetConfig([r, ...this.router.config]);
    console.log(this.router.config);
  }
```

I have found that after trying to access the newly added route by typing it in the browser URL the newly added route object disappears from the route array. Hence I am getting that error.

Following image is before I add the dynamic route object

[image]

This is after I add the route object

[image]

But when I try to access the `/module3` route by accessing it in the URL,
it just reinitializes the route object array and therefore it doesn't contain the newly added route.

My question is how I can persist this newly added route to the initial route object array. So that it will be there when I try to access it by URL.

I have added sample angular project for this scenario in the following GitHub repo.

https://github.com/mal90/ng-dynamic-route

If anyone can point me in the right direction is much appreciated!

Comment: Does it work when you click on the module3 link from your page?

Comment: yes. it works from the page after adding dynamically.

Comment: did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

Angular is a client side framework so when you add a new route dynamically it's only effective as long as you do not try to access a page from a server request, which is the case when you enter a URL in the browser

Answer (score 0):

As David pointed out, your approach is precise headshot for Angular app. Looking at your profile, you seem to know about Node.js and you have rather good score, so I presume there must be good reason for you going with this highly specific road. If you really want to do such a crazy thing (I cannot see the reason why to do it ... I think you should rather use server-side solution) you might try storing the router definitions in some local storage or external file and force app to redirect any path to some specific route, then to force the app to redefine the router, initialise it again and only then navigate to the new component. As you can see, you will need a lot of force to do this. Some people had already similar ideas. Such as in this post [about external definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40867878/loading-routers-paths-from-external-files) Do not take me wrong, I like crazy ideas. You could probably hack the environment somehow. But I think it is not worth it.